# How to implement a collapsible / expandable tree structure for RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a tree structure of nodes (think folders and files) that I'd like to show in a RecyclerView. I have it working with all nodes visible, but I'm stumped trying to implement collapsing and expanding the nodes.

This is what I have so far. The basic node looks like this:

```
public class Node {
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    Node parent = null;
    String name = "";

    // If 'false', do not show child views
    boolean visible = true;
}
```

The adapter takes a `List` of nodes and populates them as such:

```
private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

// Takes a list of root-level nodes and "flattens"
// them to the nodes fields
public void addNodes(List<Node> nodes) {
    for(Node n : nodes) {
        this.nodes.add(n);
        addNodes(n.children);
    }
}

// Binds a node to a viewholder
@Override
void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(nodes.get(position).name);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Collapse / expand the children of the node
            toggleNode(nodes.get(position));
        }
    });
}

// This "works", but tends to get screwed up after a while,
// especially when hiding and showing nodes at different depths
// in the same hierarchy
private void toggleNode(Node node) {      
     node.visible = !node.visible;
     for(Node child : node.children) {
         if(node.visible) notifyItemInserted(nodes.indexOf(child));
         else notifyItemRemoved(nodes.indexOf(child));
     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work as intended?

Comment: this is a userfull example, link is [here](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view)

Comment: @android_griezmann AFAIK it doesn't work for n depth levels - only with parent and child views.

Comment: Sorry my bad! here is another [link](https://github.com/defacto133/MultiLevelExpandableIndentableListView)

Comment: It is not the RecylerView, but may help. [TreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView)